# Convert parallel LVDS to csi-2

Tags: fpga, serial, interface, camera, conversion

I have a camera outputing parallel data and I want to interface it with iMX6 module which accepts CSI-2 camera data.

Are there any ready & cheap solutions to convert parallel into CSI-2.

Lattice have some FPGA solutions but I do not want to pay for development software licenses just for this purpose.

thx

Comment: Have you tried googling for answers?

Comment: AFAIK All FPGA tools are free these days. Lattice definitely, I have it. There is no simple solution CSI is a complex analogue protocol, a mixture of LVDS and I2C. I think Xilinx have managed to use two pairs of I/O pins in different modes which work.

Comment: It all depends on the speed - what is the data rate per lane?

Comment: @oldfart: They are not free. Lattice requires a payed license for the larger FPGAs (those with SERDES mostly)

Comment: @oldfart the toolchains aren't free for all FPGAs; usually only the smaller ones.  Also, the FPGA vendor supplied CSI IP cores probably aren't free.